# Имитация событий

Tags: javascript

Как имитировать события? Например, имитировать клик по кнопке, чтобы не кликать вручную.

Comment: `element.click()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
setInterval(function(){
  var e = new Event("click");
  document.getElementById("test").dispatchEvent(e);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<button id="test" onclick="console.log('clicked')">Do not click</button>
```